# How to check if current facebook user like a page using PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook

How can i check if the current facebook user like a facebook page?

I have this code,

```
require_once("/path/to/sdk/facebook.php");


    // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId' => 'APP_ID',
      'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
      try {
        $likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/153649677989200");
        if( !empty($likes['data']) )
            echo "I like!";
        else
            echo "not a fan!";
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'user_likes'
      ));
    }
```

But is not responding if the user like the page, please see the page [here](http://www.bridalbook.ph/promos/the-mystery-of-the-stolen-heart/?preview=1)

Thanks!

Comment: Please refrain from posting your app secret, it is supposed to be secret. Also regenerate a new one, now that you have exposed the old one to public. Also, could you please tell what error are you having or are you not able to retrieve anything?

Comment: thanks @AnveshSaxena it was example only, btw... it is not displaying if I already LIKE the page or NOT

Comment: This uses old api, which is not supported since 2015-05-01.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

```
$isFan = $facebook->api(array(
  "method" => "fql.query",
  "query"  => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = '<YOUR PAGE ID>' AND uid = '<UID>"
));
```

Comment: Hi @Khawer Zeshan, how can I get the value of uid dynamically?

Comment: use [getUser](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/) method `$uid = $facebook->getUser();`

Comment: Or rather use `uid= me()` to reference the current user

Comment: I'm having this error `Warning: curl_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in path/to/base_facebook.php on line 964`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you need to do this only using FQL, but there is another easier way:

```
require_once("/path/to/sdk/facebook.php");

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$like = $signed_request['page']['liked'];
```

$like will be *empty* or **1**.

I like to check variables first, like this:

```
if(is_array($signed_request) && isset($signed_request['page']) {
  if($signed_request['page']['liked']) {
    // do whatever you want to do if the user likes the page
  } else {
    // do whatever you want to do if the user don't like the page yet
  }
}
```