# How do I make sure someone likes my facebook page before entering contest?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I plan to start a Facebook contest where the user is first asked to like the page, then they submit their email to enter the contest.

I checked out other contest examples on:

http://contests.about.com/od/facebookcontests/tp/Facebook-Contests-and-Facebook-Sweepstakes.htm

Most Facebook pages direct a user to a "Like this page to continue" page. I tried to google around to find how this is done, but I cannot find anything. I tried to find ways to track specific user's likes,

For contest-specific legal reasons, I cannot use an app that makes the contest and keeps track of the entries. So I will need to create this from scratch.

I have made other apps before, and I do have access to an external server where I plan to create a page and link to it from facebook for the 'frame' type app.

Is there a standard way of doing this? Is there a documentation that I have yet to find?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Me answering my own question)

Some more googling I was able to find:

[How to check if current facebook user like a page using PHP SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168110/how-to-check-if-current-facebook-user-like-a-page-using-php-sdk)

A php version of the same question.

In that case, I will be able to check out [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/)'s documentation to find out how to get this information.

I really don't want a permission popup from facebook to pop up, and I don't think I will need that to make this work. I will try that and add a comment to this answer if it works just like what I'm looking for.